# Два блока рядом, разные по высоте

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Есть ли в этом случае возможность выровнять `<span class = "b">` по высоте как `auto`?

Как результат - нужны 2 блока, стоящие рядом, разные по высоте (`height: auto;`).

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

.a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.c {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="a">Text 1</span>
  <span class="b"><span class = "c">Text 2</span></span>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/050k7e6e/)

Comment: Я уже глаза сломал вопрос читать... Вроде не новичок.  Опиши вопрос нормально...

Comment: @Air, нужно, чтобы элементы `.a` и `.b` по высоте подстраивались под вложенный контент притом, что у родительского элемента `div` свойство `display` установлено в `flex`.

Comment: Смотрите св-во `align-items` .

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров Спасибо, помогло: `align-items: flex-start;`